# Setting the value of repeatInterval of Quartz in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I want to fetch a value from database and then set it as a value for repeatInterval for a job in Quartz plugin in grails. I did this as under.

```
class StartJob {
     def interval = Settings.first().interval

    static triggers = {
        simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 2000, repeatInterval:interval

    }
    def group = "MyGroup"
    def execute(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

fetch a first row from table `Settings` and then get its interval column and put it in the simple trigger. Now the problem is that the interval is non-static and triggers are static which gives errors due to mismatching. How can I handle this situation ? Is there any way to sort this out, trigger the job from somewhere else etc.. ?

Comment: Is it possible to set the repeatInterval outside the job class and then start the job ?

Comment: Yes, check this: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html, chapter Dynamic Jobs Scheduling

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to sort this out, trigger the job from somewhere else
>   etc.. ?

Yes, you can schedule job manually like this:

```
  MyJob.schedule(Long repeatInterval, Integer repeatCount?, Map params?)
```

See other examples here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html

Answer (score 1):

> class StartJob {
>
> ```
>  static def interval =  Settings.getAll().get(0).interval
>
> static triggers = {
>     simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 2000, repeatInterval:interval
>
> }
> def group = "MyGroup"
> def execute(){
>     //do something
> } }
> ```